# Reset decorator for recursive function in Python

Tags: python, recursion, python-decorators

I am using a recursive function to solve a partition problem with a complete KK algorithm.

My algorithm searches a tree of possible partitions. I wish to prune that tree by stopping particular branches. My "pruner" wants to track the minimum result (in fact the minimum difference between the sums of two subsets found so far).

My code is of the form:

```
def prune(branch):

    def pruner(list_):
         # If only single element in list, reached end of branch
         if len(list_) == 1:
             return list_[0]

         # ... pruning code here ... 
         # Decision to prune depends on pruner.min

         # If didn't prune, calculate as usual
         # tracking minimum
         min_branch = branch(list_)
         pruner.min = min(pruner.min, min_branch)
         return min_branch

     pruner.__name__ = branch.__name__
     pruner.min = float("inf")
     return pruner


 @prune
 def branch(list_):
     # ... code to make two new branches here ...
     return min(branch(list_1), branch(list_2))
```

It works just fine for a *single* call to `branch` - `pruner.min` is set once at the beginning in my decorator - and `branch` returns the correct answer.

The problem is if I use the function twice or more in succession. In that case, `pruner.min` is not reset after each call, causing problems in my decision to prune branches.

How can I (elegantly) make it reset `pruner.min = float("inf")` for every initial (i.e. non recursive) call to my `branch` function? The only thing I can think of is adding a `first` keyword argument, `def branch(list_, first=True)`, which I set to `False` for recursive calls inside the `branch` function. My decorator could look at this argument. Is this the best way?

For completeness, here is a runnable example that results in correct answers. Any more general comments are welcome.

```
import copy

def prune(CKK_branch):
    def pruner(list_):

        internal_list = copy.deepcopy(list_)

        # Check whether end of branch or whether optimal solution achieved
        if pruner.min == 0.:
            return pruner.min
        elif len(internal_list) == 1:
            return list_[0]

        # Sort branch
        internal_list.sort(reverse=True)

        # Prune branch
        if pruner.min < internal_list[0] - sum(internal_list[1:]):
            return internal_list[0]

        # Find minimum in branch and track minimum of all branches
        min_branch = CKK_branch(internal_list)
        pruner.min = min(pruner.min, min_branch)

        return min_branch

    pruner.__name__ = CKK_branch.__name__
    pruner.min = float("inf")
    return pruner


@prune
def CKK(list_):
    internal_list = copy.deepcopy(list_)
    # Replace maximum two numbers by their difference and their sum in two
    # branches
    diff = internal_list[0] - internal_list[1]
    sum_ = internal_list[0] + internal_list[1]
    sum_tree = copy.deepcopy(internal_list)
    diff_tree = copy.deepcopy(internal_list)
    del sum_tree[0:2]
    del diff_tree[0:2]
    sum_tree.append(sum_)
    diff_tree.append(diff)

    return min(CKK(diff_tree), CKK(sum_tree)) 

example_list_1 = [1.4,
                  10.1,
                  19.55,
                  11.71,
                  51.7,
                  122.1
                  ]
example_list_2 = [10,
                  5,
                  1,
                  1
                  ]   
print CKK(example_list_1)
print CKK(example_list_2)
print CKK(example_list_1)
# 27.64  # Correct (122.1) - (1.4, ...)
# 3  # Correct (10) - (5, 1, 1)
# 122.1  # Something went wrong
```

Comment: can you add a runnable example?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham sure, hope it's clear enough, the longer code snippet should be runnable for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can set a flag  to `None` and in CKK pass in any value like you would use a default arg:

```
import copy

def prune(CKK_branch):
    def pruner(list_, flag=None):
        internal_list = copy.deepcopy(list_)
        if flag is None:
            pruner.min = float("inf")
        # Check whether end of branch or whether optimal solution achieved
        if pruner.min == 0.:
            return pruner.min
        elif len(internal_list) == 1:
            return list_[0]
        # Sort branch
        internal_list.sort(reverse=True)    
        # Prune branch
        if pruner.min < internal_list[0] - sum(internal_list[1:]):
            return internal_list[0]  
        # Find minimum in branch and track minimum of all branches
        min_branch = CKK_branch(internal_list)
        pruner.min = min(pruner.min, min_branch)
        return min_branch
    pruner.__name__ = CKK_branch.__name__
    return pruner


@prune
def CKK(list_):
    internal_list = copy.deepcopy(list_)
    # Replace maximum two numbers by their difference and their sum in two
    # branches
    diff = internal_list[0] - internal_list[1]
    sum_ = internal_list[0] + internal_list[1]
    sum_tree = copy.deepcopy(internal_list)
    diff_tree = copy.deepcopy(internal_list)
    del sum_tree[0:2]
    del diff_tree[0:2]
    sum_tree.append(sum_)
    diff_tree.append(diff)
    return min(CKK(diff_tree,True), CKK(sum_tree,True))
```

Each time `min(CKK(diff_tree,True), CKK(sum_tree,True))` is called you will reset the min value to inf.

```
In [26]:  CKK(example_list_1)
Out[26]: 27.639999999999993

In [27]:  CKK(example_list_2)
Out[27]: 3

In [28]:  CKK(example_list_1)
Out[28]: 27.639999999999993
```

Comment: I think `pruner` calls itself, but `prune` is supposed to keep track of the minimum per-outer-call.

Comment: Thanks, that looks like it'll do it.

Answer (score 0):

Why not add another layer?

```
def prune(f):
    def wrapper(branch):
        def wrapped(branch):
            ...
        wrapper.min = float('inf')
        return wrapped(branch)
    return wrapper
```

Now your decorator will return a closure that calls its nested function.

Comment: Won't this reset `wrapper.min = float('inf')` too often? It will end up getting the right result, but by brute force, as it essentially turns off pruning by setting `wrapper.min = float('inf')` at each step.

Comment: No, because `wrapped` is the one that should be setting and checking `.min`, and the one you're recursing on.

Comment: Ah but unfortunately `wrapped` requires the previous value of `wrapper.min`, i.e. `wrapper.min = float('inf')` must be executed only once at the beginning of each partition problem.

Comment: @innisfree that's not a problem, since `wrapped` doesn't get executed until it's called, and by then you've defined `wrapper.min`

Comment: could you make a runnable code, preferably my modifying my complete code? When doing so, add e.g. a `print("pruned")` every time it prunes a branch, so we can see the behaviour.

Comment: I really don't think your suggestion will work, unfortunately, but I'd like to proven wrong.

Comment: @innisfree I'm not really sure why I'm being asked to "prove" my example works when you have working code already, but here's a gist https://gist.github.com/NotTheEconomist/cca4fd565eac4d436d0b